# What is the behavior of nested If's in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    if(a > 0)
    {
        cout << "we are in the first" << endl;
        if(b > 3)
        {
            cout << "we are in the second" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "we are in else" << endl;
    }
}
```

According to the C++ISO:

> In the second form of if statement (the one including else), if the
> first substatement is also an if statement then that inner if
> statement shall contain an else part. In other words, the else
> is associated with the nearest un-elsed if.

I thought that my code above would print out "we are in else", since the condition of the nearest un-elsed `if`, the inner one, resulted in false. What did I miss?

Comment: curly brackets on their own lines is easier as you learn the language.

Comment: The `{}` work a bit like brackets in maths

Comment: The quotaton is qualified on the condition "*if the first substatement is also an `if` statement*".  That is not the case in your example code, where the first `if`'s substatement is a simple compound (a `{}`-enclosed block).

Comment: Well pointed @JohnBollinger. The standard is very rigorous, I missed this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they say "nearest" then they refer to the distance to the whole `if statement`, not only the `if` keyword. The whole if statement is:

```
if (a>0){
    cout<<"we are in the first"<<endl;
    if (b>3){cout<<"we are in the second"<<endl;}
}
```

It ends at the `}`. The `}` closes the block of the outer `if` and that is the `if` which is closes to the `else`.

See also here for a little more formal explanation of the if-statement consisting of more than just the `if`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if.

Comment: To clarify, *"the first substatement"* mentioned by standard is the whole block between (and including) `{}`. It is not just an `if` statement, therefore the clause doesn't apply.

Comment: I thought that it didn't matter since I excluded the first `cout` and nothing changed, but well pointed here, it must be just an `if`

Answer (score 5):

The standard talks here about no block statements. In situation like this:

```
if (a > 0)
    if (b > 3) std::cout << "nested-if\n";
    else std::cout << "nested-else\n";
```

`else` is a part of the nested `if`. Such things must be unambiguous in standard, but I strongly recommend using block statements (wrapped in `{}`) in every situation to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Context. The part you're missing is context.

Every time you open a {} pair you introduce a new context, so the exterior else only "knows" about the first if.

The if inside the new context could have an else of it's own. If you wanted the behavior of the else being pertaining to the last if, you should not have created a new context.

E.g:

```
if (someVar == true)
    if (someOtherVar == true)
        cout << "Some text" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "Some other text" << endl;
else 
    cout << "Another entirely different text" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code -

```
    int a =1;
    int b =2;
    if (a>0)
    {
        cout<<"we are in the first"<<endl;
        if (b>3){cout<<"we are in the second"<<endl;}
    }
    else
    {
       cout<<"we are in else"<<endl;
    }
```

Logic path -

```
    int a =1;
    int b =2;
    if (1>0)
    {
        cout<<"we are in the first"<<endl;
        if (b>3){cout<<"we are in the second"<<endl;}
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"we are in else"<<endl;
    }
```

```
    int a =1;
    int b =2;
    
        cout<<"we are in the first"<<endl;
        if (b>3){cout<<"we are in the second"<<endl;}
```

`we are in else` is not executed.